# jQuery load() doesn't work on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

i've used jquery load method for a website pagination 
here is my code

```
function next_page(page)
{   

$('.aloder').fadeIn(100);
$('.maindiv .product-big').fadeOut(400); 
$('.maindiv').load('http://www.tehrantbl.ir/productlist.php?neshani=<?php echo $_REQUEST['neshani']; ?>&page='+page+' .maindiv');

}
```

for some reason it doesn't work in IE but it works fine in FF 
the page has bad html design in term of using tables instead of divs to show the items
but i dont think that's the problem  .

here is the live site

http://www.tehrantbl.ir/

to see the problem search this word and go to page 2

```
همت
```

Comment: why don't you think the HTML is the problem since quite a few cross browser issues are based on malformed html

Comment: can you please add some more code here

Comment: first you could try to remove double jQuery including - on lines 9 and 10 of your html, maybe they both make IE crazy?

Comment: @DrMOlle how about that every questions with an unaccepted answer has an applicable answer even one where max says something like "yes this worked" in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use to encodeURIComponent() to encode the user-input:

```
$('.maindiv')
 .load('http://www.tehrantbl.ir/productlist.php?neshani='+encodeURIComponent('<?php echo $_REQUEST['neshani']; ?>')+'&page='+page+' .maindiv');
```

The result would be:
http://www.tehrantbl.ir/productlist.php?neshani=%D9%85%D8%AA&page=2 (works for me)

instead of:
`http://www.tehrantbl.ir/productlist.php?neshani=همت&page=2` (did not work)